# How do I know if the content of my site is compatible with the meta tag X-UA-Compatible/IE=edge?

Tags: html, meta-tags

How can I tell if I should include this meta tag in my site?

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

Answer (score 0):

By testing it in various versions of IE (and, as a rule of thumb, if there are problems, fix the problems rather then telling IE to emulate an older version of itself).